# jointprior() function in "deal" package in R

Tags: r, networking, bayesian

I am trying to use the example p.39 of the book Bayesian Network in R.

But when I am typing it I got the following error:

```
    library(bnlearn)
    library(deal)
    net = network(marks)
    prior = jointprior(net, N = 5)
    Erreur dans array(1:TD, dim = Dim) : 'dims' doit être de longueur 0
```

I don't understand because with the example provided in R help, it works perfectly!

```
    data(rats)
    rats.nw    <- network(rats)
    rats.prior <- jointprior(rats.nw,12)
```

Is it because "marks" is only with continuous variables?

Comment: To run this script you need two packages: "bnlearn" and "deal". network comes from the package "deal". Marks is a dataset of examination marks of 88 students on five different topics (bnlearn). The rats dataset and the jointprior function are from deal.

Comment: Thanks! Make sure to include details such as these in future questions.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing you should do is some debugging. When you get an error,

```
prior = jointprior(net, 5)
# Error in array(1:TD, dim = Dim) : 'dims' cannot be of length 0
```

you can use `traceback` to see where the error occurred.

```
traceback()
# 3: array(1:TD, dim = Dim)
# 2: jointcont(nw, timetrace = timetrace)
# 1: jointprior(net, 5)
```

This tells you that the problem occurs in a call to `array` within the `jointcont` function that is within the `jointprior` function. For example, the same error can be seen with

```
jointcont( net, timetrace=FALSE )
# Error in array(1:TD, dim = Dim) : 'dims' cannot be of length 0
```

OK, so this tells you that `Dim` in the `array` call is probably `NULL`. You can see this because

```
array(1:1,dim=NULL)
# Error in array(1:1, dim = NULL) : 'dims' cannot be of length 0
```

If you look at the `jointcont` source by typing `jointcont` into the console, you can see that `Dim` is never modified from `c()` (i.e. `NULL`) because `net$nd` is not greater than zero (it is equal to zero). It looks like `net$nd` is the number of discrete nodes in the graph. Note that `rats.nw` has two discrete nodes (see `rats.nd$discrete`). Hence, your function doesn't run correctly because your network has no discrete nodes. It has five continuous nodes but no discrete nodes.

It appears that `discrete` nodes are made when the data frame given to `network` has a column that is a `factor`. Note that the `rats` data frame has two `factor` columns and so two discrete nodes. The `marks` data frame has five `numeric` columns and five continuous nodes, but it has no `factor` columns. You can see that the discrete and continous nodes are closed and open circles, respectively, by running `plot(rats)`.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer! So it is what I thought... I will write the authors of "Bayesian Network in R". They don't discretize the data and, apparently, find a solution without changing anything in `marks` data frame.

Comment: No problem. Feel free to accept the answer if it answers your question sufficiently.

Answer (score 3):

Though the documentation said it's able to handle datasets with both discrete and continuous variables. The reality is that it's seems error out in some function for continuous only datasets. See errata of the book see http://www.bnlearn.com/book-useR/. Where it says:

page 39: at least in modern times, deal is unable to fit a network
containing only continuous variables. A workaround is to include a
dummy factor (e.g. marks$XYZ <- factor(rep("xyz", nrow(marks)))) so
that jointprior() does not fail.